# Wrong SOAP Action header in request. Why?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying connecting to the MS CRM Deployment Service from within CRM plugin (i.e. I don't have ability to use `app.config` configuration file).

The issue is it's really difficult to replace 'configuration magic' with source code.

While I'm using following configuration file (testing locally in console application):

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://server/XRMDeployment/2011/Deployment.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IDeploymentService"
        contract="DeploymentService.IDeploymentService" name="CustomBinding_IDeploymentService">
        <identity>
            <userPrincipalName value="DOMAIN\DYNAMICS_CRM" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>

    ...

</client>
```

Everything is fine, but when I'm trying to replace configuration with code I'm facing with following. In resulting SOAP message instead of expected header:

```
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4">http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IDeploymentService/Retrieve</a:Action>
```

I see something strange:

```
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/SCT</a:Action>
```

Does anybody knows how can I override Action Header and which statement in configuration turns WCF magic making everything work?

Comment: [RST/SCT is about secure conversation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512/ws-secureconversation-1.3-os.html#_Toc162064066). I am guessing your are being challenged to provide credentials or token.

Comment: If you're just attempting to access settings that you'd normally put in the config file, why not create a new ConfigSettings entity within CRM and read your settings from there?

Comment: I don't have direct access to CRM installation...

Comment: This is caused by a mismatch in configuration.  Please post your binding from xml, and the C# you wrote to replace it.  I would recommend posting the entirety of the `System.ServiceModel` section of the `app.config` file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use something like following configuration

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "DeploymentService",
    Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/")]
public interface IDeploymentService
{
    [OperationContract(Action="uri://<your service URI>/Retrieve")]
    void Retrieve();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can customize your soap action in the service interface class,

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
   {
     [OperationContract(
        Action = "MySoapAction" ]
      Message ServiceFunction(Message input);
   }
```